# Group data by columns and show all rows that meet criteria + extra data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my data:

```
ID  DATA1  DATA1EXTRA   DATA2  DATA2EXTRA    DATA3   DATA3EXTRA  
1   yes    EXTRADATA11                       yes     EXTRADATA31
2                       yes    EXTRADATA22
3                       yes    EXTRADATA23   yes     EXTRADATA33
```

What I like to get:

```
column 1   column 2
DATA1
- ID1      EXTRADATA11
DATA2
- ID2      EXTRADATA22
- ID3      EXTRADATA23
DATA3
- ID1      EXTRADATA31
- ID3      EXTRADATA33
```

Anyone knows what query or formula I can use for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Use filter and join for three array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
= filter
  (
    { B1,"";
      "- " & A1 & A2:A4,C2:C4;
      D1,"";
      "- " & A1 & A2:A4,E2:E4;
      F1,"";
      "- " & A1 & A2:A4,G2:G4
    },
    { "Yes"; B2:B4;
      "Yes"; D2:D4;
      "Yes"; F2:F4
    }="Yes"
  )
```

[image]